# Prove $f(x) \rightarrow l \ $ as $ \ x \rightarrow a \ \iff \ f(x_{n}) \rightarrow l \ $ as $ \ n \rightarrow \infty \ $, ($a$ is a limit point)

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Suppose $ S \subset \mathbb{R}^{N} \ $ and $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{M} \ $ Let $a$ be a limit point of $S$ and let $l \in \mathbb{R}^{M}$. 
Prove

$f(x) \rightarrow l \ $ as $ \ x \rightarrow a \ $ if and only if $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow l \ $ as $ \ n \rightarrow \infty \ $ for all sequences $\;\{x_n\}\subset S \setminus \{a\}\;$ converging to $a$.

I'm not sure how to go about this; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you come cross the episilon-delta definitions for convergence of sequences and continuity? The lhs can also be phrased as continuous at x=a, for the other direction, you need to show the contrapositive statement

Comment: I have come across those definitions but I wasn't sure how to apply them. Could you possibly start off the proof?

Comment: In the second statement, don't you mean $n \rightarrow \infty$ instead of $x \rightarrow \infty$? You also need to define $x_n$, is it a sequence of points where $x_n \rightarrow a$ as we have $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: I've changed that now, sorry. As for $x_{n}$, they are sequences in S\{a} - I'm not sure how to write that in latex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof: "$\to$"  Since $f(x) \rightarrow l \ $ as $ \ x \rightarrow a$,for any $\epsilon>0$,there is $\delta>0$ so that if $|x-a|<\delta$,we have$$|f(x)-l|<\epsilon.$$
Then for any sequence $x_n\to{a}$,it is cauchy,i.e. for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $N>0$ such that $|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon$ for all $n,m>N$. Let $\epsilon=\delta$,we will show that $f(x_n)$ is cauchy.By triangle inequality,$$|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|\leq|f(x_n)-l|+|f(x_m)-l|<2\epsilon$$
for any $n,m>N$.

For the other diriction: By controdiction,suppose that $lim_{x\to{a}}f(x)\neq{l}\;$. Then there is $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for any $\delta>0$,there exist x with $|x-a|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-l|>\epsilon_0$ .

Now let $\delta_{n}=1/n$, we can obtain a sequence $x_n$ and $|x_n-a|<1/n\;$ , i.e. $\;x_n\to a\;$  but $|f(x_n)-l|>\epsilon_0\;$ , which is a contradiction.

Comment: Should that not be $|x - a| \lt \delta$ in the first line?

Comment: Yes, Thank you!

Comment: Could you go into a little more detail with the triangle inequality?

Comment: Yes,I have added the triangle inequality!

Comment: So in this particular instance, you could set up the inequality as $|f(x_{n}) - f(x)| \leq |f(x_{n}) - l| + |l - f(x)| \leq 2\epsilon$ And we have
$|l - f(x)| \lt \epsilon$ as earlier stated so $|f(x_{n}) - l| \lt \epsilon$ Thus $f(x_n) \rightarrow l$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

As stated, the claim is false as it is equivalent to $\;f\;$ being continuous at $\;x=a\;$ . For example, take

$$f(x)=\sin\frac1x\;,\;\;a=0\;,\;\;x_n:=\frac1{2n\pi }$$

then

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)\;\;\text{doesn't exist, yet}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin2n\pi=0$$

Comment: This is a theorem so that claim can't be false..?

Comment: Yes, like books/teachers can't be wrong *ever*, uh? Well, I just showed you a counter example so either I am wrong (which wouldn't be that rare at all), or else that book/teacher/whatever is wrong. What do you think?

Comment: If $y_n:=\frac1{2n\pi+\pi/2 }$ ,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(y_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(2n\pi+\pi/2)=1.$$ The condition should be "for any sequence $x_n\to{a}$,then $f(x_n)\to{l}$".

Comment: I'm not saying they're never wrong, it would just be unusual for them to give us a false theorem to prove.

Comment: I also think so, @F.G...yet the OP commented above that "it is a theorem so the claim can't be false...".

Comment: Perhaps they missed some condition or, maybe much more probably, you forgot an additional condition, @Mathlete

Comment: I included the forgotten condition in the comments below the question earlier.

Comment: I can't see where you did that, @Mathlete, but anyway: any *forgotten* condition **must** be added in the body of the question.

Comment: I think $x_n$ should satisfy the condition that  $lim_{n\to{+\infty}}x_n=a$.

Comment: Of course, @F.G : my counterexample fulfills that. What's important here is the omission of "for **all** sequences such that...", or continuity of the function at $\;x=a\;$ .

Comment: Sorry, yes it does satisfy that condition @F.G

Comment: Yes, it's Heine's THM.

Comment: The only reason I didn't include in the body was due to my limited capabilities with Latex, my bad @DonAntonio

Comment: What theorem by Heines, @F.G ? I don't recognize it.

Comment: Don't worry, @Mathlete . Now just add the *correct* condition in your question: "...$\;\iff\;$ for **all** sequences $\;\{x_n\}\;$ s.t. $\;x_n\to a\;$ then $\;f(x_n)\to l\;$ ...."

Comment: Just edited the body; please feel free to redo my edit if it still isn't clear.

Comment: Now it's fine, @Mathlete . Check the editing I did to your edited question so that you'll learn some useful LaTeX symbols